# Using Oracle regexp_replace to capture multiple strings or words

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I have data in a line like this.

**age:32, name:Michael John, country:USA, age:34, name:Lewis Carl, country:USA, age:53, name:Larry Moore, country:Mexico**

And I would like to capture all the names from above line.

expected output:-

**Michael John, Lewis Carl, Larry Moore**

How can I achieve that?

Please take note I show 3 datasets but the dataset is dynamic and can be more than 3. So the expected name list can be more than 3.

I have tried this way

**select
regexp_replace(s1,'(name:\w+( +\w+)*)','<\1>')
from (
select 'age:32, name:Michael John, country:USA, age:34, name:Lewis Carl, country:USA, age:53, name:Larry Moore, country:Mexico' s1 from dual
)
;**

here is the output

**age:32, <name:Michael John>, country:USA, age:34, <name:Lewis Carl>, country:USA, age:53, <name:Larry Moore>, country:Mexico**

But I have no idea how to remove the "age" and "country" that I would like to omit.

Please advise.

Comment: What you show is not "three datasets" - it's only a single row with three occurrences of "name". Right? Or are those really **three** rows (three input strings), with a single name in each? If it's a single input string with three names in it - do you always have only ONE string to process, or will you need to process several strings ("lines") - with varying numbers of "names" in each string - at the same time? And, what is your Oracle version?

Comment: You re right. It is always single line. And the key 'name' will appear multiple times but not limit to 3. My bad if I use term dataset wrongly. My oracle version is 12cr2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT RTRIM( REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '\s*(name:([^,]+,?)|[^,]+,?)', '\2' ), ',' ) AS names
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'age:32, name:Michael John, country:USA, age:34, name:Lewis Carl, country:USA, age:53, name:Larry Moore, country:Mexico'
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | NAMES                               |
> | :---------------------------------- |
> | Michael John,Lewis Carl,Larry Moore |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=761343ad59c1eaa26f56b5570540f1c9)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Mind to explain how the reg exp works? I am just new to learn about it.